# Displaying my custom taxonomies in a <ul> using the_term_list()

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I need help with displaying my custom taxonomies in a ul using the_term_list().

I can get it to list all the terms I want, but I need them in an unordered list, rather than just a list of links separated by comments.

Here's what I've got to work with:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'skills', '<h5>Project Role</h5> ', ', ', '', ); ?>
```

Here's the WordPress function reference, if you need it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
 <?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'skills', '<h5>Project Role</h5><ul><li> ', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' ); ?>
```

Comment: That's what I came up with, but it lacks any sort of hierarchy. Thank you, though!